# gridview edit mode is not getting fired on single click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to edit the record in gridview on single click. My gridview is placed inside update panel. 
There is a search textbox given and  when I type anything in search textbox "txt_Search_TextChanged" event is fired and that text is searched in database and that particular record is fetched and bind to the grid.

Now my problem is: If I click on edit button of grid without searching, then event is fired. But if I search any record and then I click on edit button, it takes 2 click to give result. I have written a script for textbox which is as follows:

```
enter code here
                <script>
            function RefreshUpdatePanel() {
            __doPostBack('<%= txt_Search.ClientID %>', '');

     };
```

below is aspx code

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div style="border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: #FDAC4C; width: 95%; border-radius: 10px;">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView ID="grd_Master" ShowFooter="false" runat="server" Width="98%" AllowPaging="true" PagerStyle-CssClass="paging"
                            OnPageIndexChanging="grd_Master_PageIndexChanging"
                            PageSize="8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="#FDAC4C" OnRowEditing="grd_Master_RowEditing" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFFF" Height="30px" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1"
                                BorderColor="#DDDDDD" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF0DD" Height="30px" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1"
                                BorderColor="#DDDDDD" />

                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Serial No.<br />

                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%" CssClass="grdrow"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSRNO" runat="server" Style="padding-right: 50px" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Cooling_Code" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<% #Bind("Cool_Code")%>'></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblProdGrpCode" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 100px" Text='<% #Bind("Prod_Grp_Code")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSubProdGrpCode" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 100px" Text='<% #Bind("Sub_Prod_Code")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMakeCode" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 100px" Text='<% #Bind("Make_Code")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblRegerCode" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 100px" Text='<% #Bind("Refg_Code")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCompressorCode" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 100px" Text='<% #Bind("Comp_Code")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblFilePath" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="padding-left: 100px" Text='<% #Bind("Document_Path")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdheader" Width="10%" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Cooling Name 
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="20%" CssClass="grdrow"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCoolingName" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 10px" Text='<% #Bind("Cool_Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="grdheader" Width="20%" />
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Short Name
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="grdheader" Width="15%"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="15%" CssClass="grdrow"></ItemStyle>

                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCoolingShortName" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 10px" Text='<% #Bind("Cool_Short_Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>

                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Cooling Description
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="45%" CssClass="grdrow"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCoolingDescr" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 10px" Text='<% #Bind("Cool_Descr")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="grdheader" Width="45%"></HeaderStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        Action<br />

                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="grdheader" Width="10%"></HeaderStyle>
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" CssClass="grdrow"></ItemStyle>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.png" Width="20px" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="Edit" Height="20px" />
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/trash1.png" ToolTip="Delete" OnClick="ImageDelete_Click" Width="25px" Height="20px" OnClientClick="return confirmDelete()" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>
                            <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None" />

                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txt_Search" />
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grd_Master" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Below is cs code for rowediting

```
protected void grd_Master_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        tab0.Enabled = false;
        tab1.Enabled = true;

        grd_Master.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridViewRow rw = (GridViewRow)grd_Master.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
        Label CoolingCode = (Label)rw.FindControl("Cooling_Code");
        Label ProdgrpCode = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblProdGrpCode");
        Label SubProdCode = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblSubProdGrpCode");
        Label MakeCode = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblMakeCode");
        Label ReferCode = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblRegerCode");
        Label CompressoreCode = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblCompressorCode");
        Label CoolingName = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblCoolingName");
        Label CoolingName_Short = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblCoolingShortName");
        Label CoolingName_Desc = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblCoolingDescr");
        Label lblFilePath = (Label)rw.FindControl("lblFilePath");




        txtCoolType.Text = CoolingName.Text.Trim();
        txtCoolTypeShortname.Text = CoolingName_Short.Text.Trim();
        txtCoolTypeDescrip.Text = CoolingName_Desc.Text.Trim();

        ddlProdGrp.SelectedValue = ProdgrpCode.Text;
        ddlSubProd.SelectedValue = SubProdCode.Text;
        ddlMake.SelectedValue = MakeCode.Text;
        ddlCompressor.SelectedValue = CompressoreCode.Text;
        ddlRefe.SelectedValue = ReferCode.Text;

        btnsave.Text = "Update";
        ViewState["CoolingCode"] = CoolingCode.Text;
        TabContainer_Item.ActiveTabIndex = 1;

        Session["CoolingCode"] = CoolingCode.Text;
        this.fu1.BindGridDoc();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Master.ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
    }
}

protected void txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = gn.ExecuteDataset("Search_CoolingType", txt_Search.Text.Trim());

        ViewState["CoolingTypeData"] = ds.Tables[0];
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            FillEmptyGrid();

        }
        else
        {

            grd_Master.DataSource = ds;
            grd_Master.DataBind();

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Master.ErrorMessage(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the grid has focus.  The initial click is likely just setting focus on the grid, and then it sees the second click as starting your edit.

A simple `ActiveControl = grd_Master;` at the end of the `txt_Search_TextChanged` event should do the trick.

Comment: I am not getting ActiveControl property in Code. How to set that property. Can you please guide.